# Whenever I power off my PC I get an error "Failed to unmount partition"

Tags: mount, fstab

Whenever I poweroff my PC, I get an error message saying "failed to unmount /media/Windows" This is the partition that contains the Windows OS that is bitlocker encrypted. I'm using dislocker in fstab to mount it.

Should I be worried? How do I solve this issue?

This is the fstab entry: `/media/c/dislocker-file /media/Windows  auto    nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=C:   0   0`

This is the `fdisk -l` entry: `/dev/nvme0n1p4   1595392 347955199 346359808 165.2G Microsoft basic data`

Comment: Can you output the log error, the ‘fstab’ entry and perhaps even confirm your disk setup by a ‘fdisk-l’?

Comment: I checked the logs and couldn't find any entry referring to this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo umount -l`

From man umount :

> -l, --lazy : Lazy unmount.  Detach the filesystem from the file hierarchy now, and
> clean up all references to this filesystem as soon as it is not busy
> anymore.

I also use `-v` for verbose. Works with dislocker partitions.